# How does approxPolyDP and epsilon parameter work?

Tags: c++, opencv

Could someone give a good explanation about how epsilon works?

This is how I use it.

```
cv::approxPolyDP(contour, approx, cv::arcLength(contour, true) * precision, true);
```

As default `double precision=0.02`.

Somthing that doesn't make sense to me is that the lower `precision` is the less strict the shape detection gets?

For example if I'm looking for rectangle contours in an image and not all rectangular contours are detected and `precision` is set to `0.5` (higher) even fewer rectangular contours are detected as rectangles. But if I set `precision` to `0.01` (lower) more rectangular contours are detected???

Shouldn't it be the other way around? Lower `precision` = more strict shape detection?

Comment: DP stands for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm and that explains the entire algorithm -- it's not detecting shapes, it's approximating contours. tighter epsilon means more faithful approximation, which implies more points left standing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz create an answer :)

Comment: without seeing those input contours, I can't comment much on your observations. I'd say the contours were simplified to something even less than a quad, i.e. triangle or worse. 0.5 * arclength is quite severe and bound to kill almost every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`approxPolyDP` implements the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

The algorithm does not *detect* shapes, it *simplifies* contours.

It removes points that contribute very little (epsilon) to the shape of the contour. Colinear points are a trivial case because they contribute *zero* to the shape of the contour. The most prominent corners are left standing. The result is an approximation of the input contour.

A tighter epsilon forces a more faithful approximation, leaving more points left standing, down to *all points* remaining (no action).

Note that in the case of a square/rectangle/quad with even just *rounded corners*, the locations of the *edges* of the quad are *not maintained*. Points on the *rounded corners* remain. However, the approximation can be used to *segment* the original contour, discard "corner" points, and work with edge points.